# How to give border for check box in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile, checkbox

I want to add a border for my checkboxes in jquery mobile. I have tried using the border attribute and outline attributes of css for styling.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-0" style="outline: 3px solid #1e5180;"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" style="border: 3px solid #1e5180;"/>
```

But didn't work for me. Can someone please provide a solution?

Comment: If you want to style a native checkbox then answer is no, you cant style a native checkbox. Only way you can do it is to create a custom checkbox and through it manipulate a original one.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery-mobile checkboxes:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-checkboxes.html

You can customize the styling by targeting .ui-btn-up-c

```
.ui-btn-up-c {
   border: 1px solid #999999;
}
```

Or build your own theme here:

http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/

Comment: Hi I have used jquery-mobile checkboxes, but my requirement is to apply border color for the checkbox, which I couldnt do.

Comment: @Naga Srikanth, You will need to override the css styles of .ui-btn-up-c, I updated my answer to explain.